# Combine Multiple Tables into a new table using SQL,by selecting necessary columns from parent table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

1. I'm having around **50 tables** and all those **tables are updated every minute**.
2. from those 50 tables i want to create a **brand new table**, that will contain **necessary columns**.
3. **If any data added in parent table it need to reflect on new table.**
4. All those tables are interconnected to each other.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Please tell with database are you using

Comment: Maybe what you need is to create a view with many unions or joins
depends on your tables structure

All tables have the same columns?

Comment: Lets consider ,we've A,B,C,D,E,F etc.. tables are present,A&D,B&C,D&F.... contain same column

Comment: I'm using Google BigQuery.